# ASP.NET "asp-route" Tag Helper polymorfisme

Tags: asp.net-mvc, polymorphism, tag-helpers

So I have a parent class called Item:

```
public class Item {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public double Price {get; set;}
}
```

The Bread and Cookie class inherit from this class:

```
public class Bread : Item {
    public string Type {get; set;}
}
```

```
public class Cookie : Item {
    public string Flavour {get; set;}
    public string Size {get; set;}
}
```

I display these in a table on a Razor View with a "AddToCart" button.

```
@using Data.Entities
@model ViewModels.CookieIndexViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Cookie list";
}

<h1>Our collection of cookies:</h1>

<table class="table">

    @foreach (var cookie in Model.Cookies)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@cookie.Flavour</td>
            <td>@cookie.Size</td>
            <td>@cookie.Price</td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-primary text-white" asp-action="AddItem" asp-controller="Cart" asp-route-item="@cookie">Purchase</a></td>
        </tr>

    }
</table>
```

And in the CartController I have the methode AddItem that takes an Item as parameter

```
public IActionResult AddItem(Item item)
{
    return View();
}
```

But this doesn't work because Cookie can not be converted to an Item any tips on how to do this?

Comment: I do not see any 'Size' property in either your parent class 'Item' or in child class 'Cookie'. How would you expect to have it in the view?

Comment: Oh that one is in the cookie class i forgot to add that one. Ill edit it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But this doesn't work because Cookie can not be converted to an Item
>   any tips on how to do this?

That's not the issue here. What you are trying to do is stuff a model (a complex tyep) into a single parameter. That's not how http query parameters works and not how MVC model binding works.

Take your Controller action:

`public IActionResult AddItem(Item item)`

This won't try to bind a single property called `item`. It will try to parse the *properties* of the model (`id`, `price`). So you need to be passing these individually.

My solution would be to pass *just the item id*. Why would you need to pass the price? That's a security issue. Someone might change the price in the request!?

```
        <tr>
            <td>@cookie.Flavour</td>
            <td>@cookie.Size</td>
            <td>@cookie.Price</td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-primary text-white" asp-action="AddItem" asp-controller="Cart" asp-route-id="@cookie.Id">Purchase</a></td>
        </tr>
```

```
public IActionResult AddItem(Guid id)
{
    //lookup item 
    //add to cart

    return View();
}
```